why there are 2 plans executing at the same time? should I tune this cases?
I am working tuning the top resource consuming queries but I have a doubt about this behaivor of apparently being executed 2 execution plans at the same time, could you please share feedback? is it an issue? Should I tune those cases as well? thnks.
Im using Query Store for tunning but I don't know these scenarios, I expect to have theses cases clear, Is it an error or it is not, What should I take in account before I tune them (if should I)
Query store executing 2 plans at the same time?
